# List all partition labels

Tags: disk, partitioning

Is there a command to list all partition labels?

I can list the partitions with

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

but it doesn't show the labels of unmounted partitions.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14165/66803

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply labels?

```
$ ls /dev/disk/by-label/              
Download  MuruHome  Ubuntu  Windows8  arch
```

Or better:

```
$ tree /dev/disk/by-label/  # or use ls -l
/dev/disk/by-label/
├── Download -> ../../sda6
├── MuruHome -> ../../sdc2
├── Ubuntu -> ../../sdc1
├── Windows8 -> ../../sda2
└── arch -> ../../sda1
```

If you're willing to use `sudo` (which `blkid` requires), then you could also use the [`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsblk) command:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,LABEL
NAME                    LABEL
sda                     
├─sda1                  System Reserved
├─sda2                  windows
├─sda3                  ubuntu
├─sda4                  
├─sda5                  arch
├─sda6                  
│ └─lvmg-homelvm (dm-0) homelb
└─sda7                  
sdb                     
└─sdb1                  
  └─lvmg-homelvm (dm-0) homelb
```

Comment: great, I will use `sudo lsblk -f` then  at my script http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157102/automate-chroot-into-broken-system/157107#157107

Comment: sudo not required on my Artful box.

Comment: @GringoSuave excellent, that bug has finally been fixed then.

Answer (score 22):

```
sudo blkid -o list
```

lists all devices with labels:

```
device          fs_type  label     mount point         UUID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1       ntfs     WINRE_DRV (not mounted)       604C3A6A4C3A3B5C
/dev/sda2       vfat     SYSTEM_DRV (not mounted)      6C3C-72E3
/dev/sda3       vfat     LRS_ESP   (not mounted)       5240-1BEE
/dev/sda5       ntfs     Windows8_OS /media/Win8       A47A42FF7A42CDAC
/dev/sda6       ntfs     Daten     /media/Daten        72860971860936DF
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use the command

```
lsblk -nPo  MOUNTPOINT,UUID,LABEL
```

You will get a list of fields that are most useful for your requirement.