# Grub not finding Windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I recently had a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1, separated by partition. I had to do a clean install of Ubuntu on the partition with Ubuntu on it due to some problems I had with the kernel version.

I ran boot-repair and [this was the output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10575234/). From my understanding (which is little), I think I deleted the windows partition with the new Ubuntu partition.

Comment: you have kicked windows out of your system, keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, the only remains of your Windows installation is the (U)EFI partition at the beginning of the disk (vfat). The other two partitions are Ubuntu (ext4) and a swap partition. You can see it here:

```
Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2       1,050,624 1,448,605,695 1,447,555,072 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sda3   1,448,605,696 1,465,147,391    16,541,696 Swap partition (Linux)
```

I'm not sure what your question is from this point, but if you haven't made a back-up of your personal data from your Windows partition, then it will be very hard (or impossible?) to recover anything, however others might know more about data recovery than I do. (If that is your question, please make it clearer in your description.)

However, if you want to reinstall Windows, you should be able to do so from an installation drive. It is usually considered harder or riskier to install Windows on top of Ubuntu, but if you manage your partitions carefully and recover GRUB at the end of the installation process, you should be able to get the job done.

To manage your partitions before installing Windows, I suggest using GParted on a live session. See this AskUbuntu question on managing partitions with GParted : [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Also, for the final step, see this article on recovering GRUB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

Comment: [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) *might* be able to recover some of the files from the lost Windows installation, but it will be hard to sift through what's found. Also, PhotoRec is usually run on empty disk space or empty partitions. I'm not sure how it will do on, or if it will pose any problems to, a partition with data that's overwritten the partition you're trying to recover. If recovery is important, ***stop using the installed OS immediately*** and run PhotoRec from an emergency disk, with another disk to store recovered files.

Answer (score 0):

> GUID Partition Table detected.
>
> Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
> /dev/sda1           2,048     1,050,623     1,048,576 EFI System partition
> /dev/sda2       1,050,624 1,448,605,695 1,447,555,072 Data partition (Linux)
> /dev/sda3   1,448,605,696 1,465,147,391    16,541,696 Swap partition (Linux)
>
> "blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________
>
> Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL
>
> /dev/sda1        13FA-FFBA                              vfat
> /dev/sda2        cc6c7c44-7e9c-438c-a43b-1445a9414e5f   ext4
> /dev/sda3        37127360-f402-48ad-bcc0-7763e6cb7daa   swap

According to these you no longer have a NTFS (file system used by modern Windows) partition, so chances are that you wiped out your Windows 8.1 partition.

If you want to try and list all partitions go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527790/list-all-partition-labels) for some help.
If you still think that you can recover something, go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546959/new-to-ubuntu-grub-recovery-help).